# Unable to click on Submit button in Remote Machine where BitDefender is installed using Webdriver in Java. Please find the details below

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Unable to click on Submit button in Remote Machine where BitDefender is installed using Webdriver in Java. The issue is:

I have to execute my test scripts by creating a jar file in Remote Machine, where BitDefender is installed in it. when executing the jar file in IE browser in Remote Machine, I am Unable to click on Submit button (find Screenshot1), because the BitDefender tool bar is coming on Submit button when running it using Webdriver. I am getting an Exception here.

[image]

Actually when executing it Manually, I can click on Submit button with out any issues, i can click on it as in Screenshot2

[image]

Please can any one help me out on this issue without closing or moving the BitDefender tool bar in IE browser. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your second screenshot shows that additional bar, with edit to the left, what is that and why is it not showing in your first screenshot? That bar missing in the first is what is causing your issue.

Comment: @ Mark Rowlands -- Thanks for the reply. Yes, the cause for my issue is this bar is coming in first screen shot. I am unable to click on Submit button because of this bar.

Comment: I was referring to the blue bar - why is that missing in the first screen shot?

Comment: While running from Selenium Webdriver, the blue bar will be missed, because the webdriver will keep the entered field on top of the screen where ever applicable in the browser.

Comment: Fair enough, I think the only way you're going to be able to click on your submit button is using the `Actions()` class. Below is an attempt to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Actions()` class.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).moveByOffset(x,y).click().build().perform();

//where x and y are the visible lower right corner of the button - you can find its dimensions from firebug or similar
```

Finally, if the element is actually part of a `form` you can just call the `.submit()` method on that form. Which would actually avoid having to click on the hidden button entirely.